# На размер какого типа данных в С влияет выравнивание?

Tags: c

На размер какого типа данных в С влияет выравнивание?

Comment: Структур, например...

Comment: только структур?

Comment: Кроме символьных типов (`char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`), размер которых всегда равен одному байту, требования по выравниванию, наверное, могут влиять на размер любого типа. Например, тип `long double` зачастую (но не всегда!) есть 80-битный IEEE 754 extended precision format. Для его хранения достаточно 10 восьмибитных байт, но на практике он обычно занимает 16 или 12 байт, в зависимости от требований по выравниванию: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21968474), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3454576).